# How To Conditionally Change Menu In Same Theme Location

Tags: menus

Is it possible to change to a different menu using conditional tags but using the same theme location?

I have 2 menu's created which I want to display conditionally in the same them location which is the secondary menu location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can easily switch menus using conditional tags.

For example If you want to show different menu for logged in user and non-logged in user then It may be like:

```
<?php
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu' ) );
} else {
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-out-menu' ) );
}
?>
```

[Read WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Different_menus_for_logged-in_users)

Comment: This is not for loggedin user. Its using conditional tags for in_category(news). If not in news category, display the default secondary nav menu. Both menu's need to use the same theme location but are different menus with different names. How do i do this?

Comment: Of course, You can do that with a category. replace is_user_logged_in() with in_category('news'). Check the single quote. [Read this for use of in_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. You can only assign one menu per theme location. Did you test the code?

Comment: It's good idea to share code you used. [Read this for how to ask questions on here. It will also help you to get better answers quickly](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) 

I am pretty sure that you can have more than one navigation at a place. 

Modify your question and share the code you used.

Comment: You can't assign more than one menu to the same theme location. Did you test your code?

Comment: Which code I should test?? The code I shared is from WP Codex. And as It will work like charm. Take your time to share your code and the theme files you are editing.

Comment: Share the code you tested and prove that it works.

Comment: The code you supplied from the Codex uses 2 seperate theme locations. I specifically asked for the same theme location using different menus, not different theme locations.

Comment: It looks like I got something wrong due to "but using the same theme location?". For me same theme location is something like after_header(), before_header() and so on.. Whatever, it looks like you want one navigation menu by combining two. For that you may strip out some html from both of the navs. like ending </ul></nav> from first nav and opening <ul><nav> from 2nd nav. This is [what i did on this site](http://www.wpavenue.com/). You may use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to acheive your goal. HTH

Comment: @sunshine Read [ask]. Also: be nice! And update your question continuously with what you've tried and what your question really is.